# Ubuntu - installing on a pendrive

Tags: usb-drive

Is it possible to install Ubuntu 13.10 on pendrive?
I don't want a Live Ubuntu from unetbootin, because everytime I run Live OS all settings gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/creating-an-ubuntu-live-usb-from-cd/

Basically this link says to use Ubuntu's Startup Disk Creator with an empty 4GB USB stick. You can configure how much to give to your persistant home directory from there.

Hope that helps.